# Always boots to windows, i dont even have the option to boot anything else

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, windows-10

I installed ubuntu on a partition, and for some reason, the grub bootloader won't start, the only boot device I can choose in bios is the windows one, I've tried changing pretty much everything in my bios, but nothing works

Comment: What brand/model system? Are both installs in same boot mode, both BIOS or both UEFI? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]